# Check a sessions variable that may not exist

Tags: javascript, php, html, session-variables

I have a session that starts if a user logs in, but certain code may be hit asking for session variables that may not exist yet, is there still a way of checking the variable here or is there another way to go about it.

PHP runs hiding a box, if a user isn't an admin, but that check could happen before the user logs in. how would i go about checking that session variables value?

I have tried moving the code to hide the box to a seperate page, like the log in page, but to no avail, the log in is a popup by the way not another window.

```
session_start();

$connect= new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'login') or die("connection failure, please try again later");

$username= $_GET["username"] ?? '';
$password= $_GET["password"] ?? '';

echo "<br>","$username";

$getsalt="SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname='$username'";

$salt= $connect->query($getsalt);

$currentsalt = "";

while($row=$salt->fetch_assoc()) {
    $currentsalt = $row["salt"];
    $_SESSION["uname"] = $row["uname"];
    $_SESSION["id"] = $row["id"];
    echo'<br>', 'is admin ', $row['is_admin'];
    $_SESSION["is_admin"] = 1;
    if($row["is_admin"] == 1) {
        echo 'is  admin';
        $_SESSION["is_admin"] = 1;
    } else {
        echo 'is not admin';
    }
}
echo "<br>","$password";
echo "<br>", $currentsalt;

if($currentsalt == null) {
        echo "user doesnt exist";
} else {
$hashed= sha1($password.$currentsalt);

echo "<br>", $hashed;

$getaccount="SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname='$username' AND pass='$hashed'";

$result= $connect->query($getaccount);

if($result-> num_rows>0) {
    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<br>","Admin name is: " . $row["uname"];
        header("Location: /index.php");
    }
} else {
    echo "<br>","sorry password was incorrect";
}
}
```

Comment: you can check if a session exists by  `if(isset($_SESSION['fieldName'])){ Session Exists }`

Comment: It would be fine to session_start() always, not only if user logs in. What about to start session at the beggining of your script?

Comment: session seems to of started, but it isnt picking up the session variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Edit: Added a new answer based on the latest comments.

I will answer your question in two parts.

#### Check if a session variable is set or not.

You can check if a variable exists by using [empty()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

```
if (empty($_SESSION['is_admin'])) {
    // do the action if the currently logged in user is not an admin
} else {
    // do the action if an admin user is logged in
}
```

> No warning is generated if the variable does not exist. That means empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to **!isset($var) || $var == false.**

#### Perform a login check on all protected pages.

It is recommended to add a login check at the top of all pages those are reserved for logged in users.

You can add a login check as follows.

Create a helper function called `checkLogin()`

```
function checkLogin(){
    if (!empty($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
        return true;
    } else {
        header("Location: https://YOUR_LOGIN_PAGE_URL");
        die();
}
```

Then, wherever you want to restrict unauthorised users accessing the page, include this `checkLogin()` function.

*Be sure you have added this function in a file common to your application*

Comment: Please elaborate. What is the value you want to check ?

Comment: Here you're checking if `$row['is_admin']` is 1. If yes, you are setting `$_SESSION['is_admin']` to zero. That mean, if `$row['is_admin']` is 1, then you will have zero as `$_SESSION['is_admin']`. Now check your logic and code once again.

Comment: yeah changed that, SESSION variables still not getting picked up, does it matter that the login code is in a seperate php file?

Comment: Post your full code (login & login check) in the question.

Comment: @ihatephp There are a few mistakes (wrong practices) in your code.
You should make the `uname` a unique field in the database if possible. 
then fetch only one record matching the username and check for the password. Then set the session variables only if the password matches. I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `if(isset($_SESSION['name']) && $_SESSION['name'] )`

this code check if variable existe and have some value

Comment: turns out issue isnt what i was checking it was what was getting passed through, wasnt passing session variables through, possibly an issue of code being over two pages

Answer (score 0):

This question is solved, although i dont know how to mark it as solved. the key was you have to start the session on every page with session_start();, thanks to invalid bot and Railson luna, either of those will now work!

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code given in the question as below.

> I have noticed some bad practices in your code and I have added comments on them. Please read them

```
<?php
session_start();
$connect= new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'login') or die("connection failure, please try again later");

$username= $_GET["username"] ?? ''; // Username and password should not be passed as a part of the URL. Use POST instead
$password= $_GET["password"] ?? ''; // Username and password should not be passed as a part of the URL. Use POST instead


// Get the details of the user having the given Username
// Make the username field unique so that no two users can have the same username.

$getsalt="SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname='$username' LIMIT 1";
$userRow = $connect->query($getsalt)->fetch_assoc();

// No user found matching username
if (empty($userRow)) {
    // Handle the errors gracefully. Redirect the user back to the login page with an error message, instead of printing an error message.
    // echo "User doesn't exist.";
    // die();
    $_SESSION['loginError'] = "No users found"; 
    header('Location: login.php');
    die();

} else {
    // User found, now check the password

    // HERE YOU CAN AVOID AN UNNECESSARY DATABASE CALL.


    $salt = $userRow['salt'];
    $passwordHash = sha1($password . $salt);
    if ($userRow['pass'] === $passwordHash) {
        // password check succeeded. Let the user logged in
        $_SESSION['uname'] = $userRow['uname'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $userRow['id'];
        if (!empty($userRow['is_admin'])) {
            $_SESSION['is_admin'] = 1;
        }
        header("Location: /index.php");
    } else {
        // Password check failed. Do not allow the user to logged in
        // Handle the errors gracefully. Redirect the user back to the login page with an error message
        // echo "Incorrect Password";
        // die();
        $_SESSION['loginError'] = "Incorrect Password"; 
        header('Location: login.php');
        die();
    }
}
```

In your `login.php`, add the following code to show an error message

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!empty($_SESSION['loginError'])) {
?>
<div class="error-message"><?php echo $_SESSION['loginError'];?> </div>
<?php 
unset($_SESSION['loginError'];// we do not need this error message anymore
} 
?>

// Rest of your login page code goes here...
```

Comment: thanks, i will be sure to make these changes, only a uni project so not massive problem using bad coding practices, but it's a nice note and it does make the code much easier to read.